# How to display a popup message roughly ever 50 seconds in python using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, time

Trying to write a python program that uses Tkinter to display a popup window every 50 or so seconds.

This is what I have, but it never runs pops up the message a second time, it only pops up once after 50 seconds.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
 
def virus(): 
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Error Message')
    root.geometry("300x300")
    messagebox.showinfo("error", "error")
    root.mainloop()
    time.sleep(50)

while True:
    virus()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def virus(): 
    global root
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Error Message')
    root.geometry("300x300")
    messagebox.showinfo("error", "error")
    time.sleep(2)
    root.destroy()

while True:
    virus()
    root.mainloop()
```

Try this.

root.destroy erases the tkinter created window so the error message can pop up again. I don't know if it meets your criteria but it works. It also uses a global variable, which I didn't manage to make it work without it.